# Is there any way of making this function more efficient in a standard browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

While profiling my web app in Chrome I found that the following function function was taking a large percentage of the total runtime for my app (which is reasonable considering how often it is used - maybe 1000 times each page load). I therefore wonder if anyone has any suggestions of how it could be improved to increase the performance?

```
function getDate(dateString) {
    re = dateString.split(/\-|\s/);
    return new Date(re.slice(0, 3).join('/') + ' ' + re[3]);
}
```

This function is given a string in the form: "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS", for example: "2014-06-06 23:45:00", and returns a Javascript date.

I am using jQuery so that is an option.

Comment: jQuery will definitely not help with performance, no.

Comment: Your variable `re` is [global](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html).

Comment: and jQuery is a DOM manipulation library so it won't help with dates or strings.

Comment: new Date(Date.parse('2014-06-06 23:45:00'))

Comment: I believe right now the problem isn't the function itself, but the number of times you're using it. You shouldn't *need* to run that function 1000+ times per page load for your website to work properly.

Comment: 1000 times only? How slow is it? Can you show us the code that is calling this function?

Comment: You can't really make that any more efficient, any difference will be minescule and not noticeable. Testing seems to indicate that you should be able to call that function a billion times a second, so it's probably not an issue -> **http://jsperf.com/date-function-test**

Comment: @Adam Merrifield The code needs to be run to pass a date which is being received in a JSON object which contains around 1000 dates.

Comment: @adeno I admit it is not much of an issue but it all adds up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not using that many array operations, and especially not using a global `re` variable, should help:

```
function getDate(dateString) {
    return new Date(dateString.replace(/-/g, "/"));
}
```

However, notice that `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` is a valid date format which will be parsed by the [`Date` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) directly (OK, maybe not in older IEs), but in a standard browser this will work as well:

```
function getDate(dateString) {
    return new Date(dateString);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Checkout the following code:

```
function getDate(dateString) {
    re = dateString.split(/\-|\s/);
    return new Date(re.slice(0, 3).join('/') + ' ' + re[3]);
}
function getDate2(d) {
    return new Date(
        d.substr(0, 4) +
        '/' +
        d.substr(5, 2) +
        '/' +
        d.substr(8, 2) +
        ' ' +
        d.substr(11, 8)
    );
}
function getDate3(d) {
    return new Date(d);
}

function benchmark(func, times) {
    var start = new Date();
    for (var i = 0; i < times; i++) {
        var temp = eval(func);
    }
    var end = new Date();
    console.log(func + 'took ' + (end - start) + ' microseconds to execute ' + times + ' times.');
}

var str = '2014-06-06 23:45:15';
benchmark("getDate(str)", 1000000);
benchmark("getDate2(str)", 1000000);
benchmark("getDate3(str)", 1000000);
```

This gave me the following results:

```
LOG: getDate(str)took 2215 microseconds to execute 1000000 times. 
LOG: getDate2(str)took 940 microseconds to execute 1000000 times. 
LOG: getDate3(str)took 270 microseconds to execute 1000000 times.
```

So, you can see the regex engine takes a high penalty in Javascript. Using `substr` reduces the execution time by more than 50%, and using the direct string (which is valid in modern Javascript runtimes) reduces the execution time by almost 90%. :-)

Comment: I would assume that `eval` is not good for performance… Why benchmark strings?

Comment: I wanted the call line in the log. However it's not benchmarking a string, it's benchmarking the execution of the eval'ed string. And, even if `eval` is taking penalty in the benchmark result, it's being the same for all three tests, so it's still a valid/fair comparison.

Comment: I was more worried about that it might prevent certain optimisations. http://jsperf.com/getting-dates has a little nicer graphics :-)